# How do you increase the size of a picture in xamarin app when you click on it, wraplayout

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to increase the picturesize (get in on the foreground) in my xamarin app? I currently use a wraplayout that i found in this github-repository:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout. I edited it, so that my own pictures are shown, but now i would like to enlarge the pictures if i click on them.

Many thanks!

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  You need to post the relevant portions of **your** code, not just a link to some repo that you copied from.

Comment: You could add tap gesture on every image ,and show the image with [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) when clicking on it , the image will be enlarged to fill the screen .